# Fetching Test data while executing SOSL query from Test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, sosl

My Visualforce page is calling Controller methods using `apex:actionFunction` and are not being executed while I am implementing the test class. Also in my test class I have test contact records which are not being fetched by the SOSL query from the Controller causing other methods to not executed.

Main controller(partial):

```
public Contact cont {get;set;}
public List<Contact> relatedConsList {get;set;}
//Constructor 
 public ParentController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    List<String> contactFields = new List<String>{'Name', 'Email'}; 
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) stdController.addFields(contactFields); 
    this.cont=(Contact)stdController.getRecord();
        Contact currentCont = [Select Id, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact WHERE Id =: cont.Id];
        relatedConsList = ParentControllerHelper.searchRelatedContacts(currentCont.FirstName, currentCont.LastName, currentCont.Id, currentCont.Email);
 }
 public List<contactWrapper> processConts(){
    if(contactList == null){
        contactList = new List<contactWrapper>();
        if(relatedConsList.size() > 0){
            System.debug('Related List not Empty: ' +relatedConsList);
            for(Contact c: relatedConsList){
                contactList.add(new contactWrapper(c));
            } 
        }
    }
    return contactList;
 }
```

Helper class(partial):

```
Public static List<Contact> searchRelatedContacts(String firstName, String lastName, String contId, String email){
    String searchTerm = '';

    if(firstName != null){
        if(lastName != null){
            searchTerm += '('+firstName+' AND '+lastName+')' ;
        } else {
            searchTerm += firstName;
        }
    } else {
        if(lastName != null) {
            searchTerm += lastName;
        }
    }
    List<Contact> relatedConsList = new List<Contact>();
    relatedConsList = [FIND :searchTerm 
                       IN ALL FIELDS
                       RETURNING Contact(
                           Name,Id,Email,Phone,MobilePhone
                           WHERE Email <> NULL AND Id <> :contId)][0]; 
    System.debug('After query: ' +relatedConsList); //Getting as Empty in test execution all the time
    return relatedConsList; 
}
```

Test class:

```
@testSetup static void setup() {

    List<Account> testAccts = new List<Account>();
    for(Integer i=0;i<2;i++) {
        testAccts.add(new Account(Name = 'TestAcct'+i));
    }
    insert testAccts;

    List<Contact> testConts = new List<Contact>();
    for (Integer i=0;i<10;i++){
        testConts.add(new Contact(FirstName = 'Test', MiddleName= 'M'+i,  LastName = 'lName', Email = 'test@test.com'+i, AccountId=testAccts[0].Id));
    }

    testConts[4].AccountId = testAccts[1].Id; //Changing AccountId 
    testConts[5].AccountId = testAccts[1].Id; 
    testConts[6].AccountId = testAccts[1].Id; 
    testConts[7].AccountId = testAccts[1].Id; 

    insert testConts;
    System.debug('Testsetup: ' +testConts[0].Id);
    System.debug('Inserted Test Cons: ' +testConts);
}

@isTest
static void testMethodForCons(){

    Contact con = [Select Id, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact LIMIT 1];
    List<Contact> testConsList = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email 
                                  FROM Contact WHERE FirstName =: con.FirstName]; //I can query the test records. 
    Test.startTest();
        PageReference pr = Page.myVFPage;
        Test.setCurrentPageReference(pr);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put( 'Id', con.Id );
        ApexPages.Standardcontroller sc = new ApexPages.Standardcontroller(con);
        ParentController ctrl = new ParentController(sc);
        Id [] fixedSearchResults= new Id[1];
        fixedSearchResults[0] = con.Id;
        Test.setFixedSearchResults(fixedSearchResults);
        //The above statements doesn't help with the Controller's SOSL execution

        ctrl.processConts(); //Not executing as SOSL not getting the test contacts list. 
    Test.stopTest();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ## [Adding SOSL Queries to Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_SOSL.htm)
>
> To ensure that test methods always
> behave in a predictable way, any Salesforce Object Search Language
> (SOSL) query that is added to an Apex test method returns an empty set
> of search results when the test method executes. If you do not want
> the query to return an empty list of results, you can use the
> Test.setFixedSearchResults system method to define a list of record
> IDs that are returned by the search. All SOSL queries that take place
> later in the test method return the list of record IDs that were
> specified by the Test.setFixedSearchResults method. Additionally, the
> test method can call Test.setFixedSearchResults multiple times to
> define different result sets for different SOSL queries. If you do not
> call the Test.setFixedSearchResults method in a test method, or if you
> call this method without specifying a list of record IDs, any SOSL
> queries that take place later in the test method return an empty list
> of results.
>
> The list of record IDs specified by the Test.setFixedSearchResults
> method replaces the results that would normally be returned by the
> SOSL query if it were not subject to any WHERE or LIMIT clauses. If
> these clauses exist in the SOSL query, they are applied to the list of
> fixed search results. For example:
>
> ```
> @isTest
> private class SoslFixedResultsTest1 {
>
>     public static testMethod void testSoslFixedResults() {
>        Id [] fixedSearchResults= new Id[1];
>        fixedSearchResults[0] = '001x0000003G89h';
>        Test.setFixedSearchResults(fixedSearchResults);
>        List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND 'test' 
>                                          IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING 
>                                             Account(id, name WHERE name = 'test' LIMIT 1)];
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: I came across this documention already. And also I can see the Test execution to run over my controller's SOSL query, but, still the variable: `relatedConsList` is getting empty. Can you please take a look at my code?

Comment: The code you included does not call this method.

Comment: Method `searchRelatedContacts` from my helper class. I am calling this in the Constructor of my Parent controller.

Comment: No `Test.setFixedSearchResults`. You don't call it in your unit test. That's what you need to fix.

Comment: Nope, including this doesn't made any difference. Still the variable: `relatedConsList` is empty.

Comment: If you can see my above updated code, I made changes as per the doc you provided. Still doesn't really help my test class.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call [Test.setFixedSearchResults](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_SOSL.htm), which basically accepts a list of records to find:

```
Test.setFixedSearchResults(new Id[] { testConts[0].Id });
```

Alter this code to include all the ID values you want to return.

Comment: I am seeing the test execution to pass over the SOSL query. But I am not sure whether it is querying the test data.

Comment: When my Controller class's constructor is being executed at unit test, will the SOSL query gets executed? If yes, will it fetch the test contact records that are created as a part of `testSetup`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem:

The call to `Test.setFixedSearchResults(fixedSearchResults);` is occurring after the constructor for the controller executes - and the constructor is the code fragment that does the SOSL

```
Test.startTest();
    PageReference pr = Page.myVFPage;
    Test.setCurrentPageReference(pr);
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put( 'Id', con.Id );
    ApexPages.Standardcontroller sc = new ApexPages.Standardcontroller(con);
    ParentController ctrl = new ParentController(sc);
    Id [] fixedSearchResults= new Id[1];
    fixedSearchResults[0] = con.Id;
    Test.setFixedSearchResults(fixedSearchResults); // too late!
```

do:

```
Test.startTest();
        PageReference pr = Page.myVFPage;
        Test.setCurrentPageReference(pr);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put( 'Id', con.Id );
        ApexPages.Standardcontroller sc = new ApexPages.Standardcontroller(con);
        Id [] fixedSearchResults= new Id[1];
        fixedSearchResults[0] = con.Id;
        Test.setFixedSearchResults(fixedSearchResults); // before constructor
        ParentController ctrl = new ParentController(sc);
```

Comment: I am still not getting any data even after changing to above. Am I still missing anything? Or the test data from testSetup won't be considered as data for querying(from controller) while executing test class?

Comment: it could be because your SOSL call is excluding the value of `contId` which is the same contact as the one you set in setFixedSearchResults - perhaps setFixedSearchResults should return a contact other than `con.Id`

Comment: I am getting this error: `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void setFixedSearchResults(List<Contact>) from the type System.Test` when I try: `Contact [] fixedSearchResults= new Contact[1];
         fixedSearchResults[0] = con;
            Test.setFixedSearchResults(fixedSearchResults);`. can you help me fix this?

Comment: @AustinEvans - you have to supply list<ID>, not List<sobject>. See sfdcfox answer

Comment: I am still unable to fetch the data(Even after successful SOSL execution) after following your's and sfdcfox's ans.

Comment: @AustinEvans has your OP been edited to reflect the latest code that you are having issues with?